# Multiple pdf byte streams to generate merged pdf produces corrupted output

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, arrays

I have following **`C#`** code which convert the input **`PDF's`** into **`byte stream`** arrays. At the mean time i also append these byte streams to produce `new byte array`. But when i save the new merged byte array, the new generated **`PDF`** is corrupted.

***Here is my C# Code:***

```
int length = 0;
int templength = 0;
byte[] rv = null;
String[] input = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\input\");
Console.WriteLine("Starting merging...");
foreach (String item in input)
{
   byte[] temp = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(item);
   length = length + temp.Length;
}
foreach (String item in input)
{
   byte[] name = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(item);
   rv = new byte[length];
   System.Buffer.BlockCopy(name, 0, rv, templength, name.Length);
   templength = name.Length;
   name = null;
}
// and save back
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\myfile.pdf", rv);
```

Comment: *But when i save the new merged byte array, the new generated PDF is corrupted.* - What makes you think that concatenating multiple PDF files results in a valid PDF file? It doesn't! (That being said, your concatenating code is flawed to begin with for more than 2 files.)

Comment: @mkl then what should i do...

Comment: Choose a PDF library for use with .Net which offers document merging (most of them do; there are differences in licensing models and payment, though) and use it. PDF is quite a complex file format; to get an impression of its complexities, you might want to take a look at its specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: @mkl Actually i want to develop for my self... do you suggest any algorithm or reference for it.

Comment: @Neon-X: the reference to start with would be the PDF reference: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Comment: *Actually i want to develop for my self* - In that case use the references, either ISO 32000-1 I pointed to or PDF Reference 1.7 @HABJAN referred to. An as a first step try parsing the PDF objects (on a low level) of a single PDF before attempting to merge multiple ones.